# JSON data from server could not be parsed

Tags: java, jquery, json, datatables

I am getting "DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error"
I know this might be a duplicate of other threads, I am using java and dataTables in my code.. I am getting the output in JSON format but its not recognized on the client-side while printing.

When I verified the JSON object in http://jsonlint.com/ its is in correct format. I am not sure what is causing this error.

> {"iTotalRecords":5,"sEcho":"1","aaData":[["V2993ASFKH230943","Honda","Accord"],["V2993A39SNF30943","Honda","CRV"],["V4833A39SNF30943","Acura","TSX"],["V4833RE9SNF30943","Acura","TL"],["V9383RE9SNF30943","Acura","MDX"]],"iTotalDisplayRecords":5}

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

            jsonResponse.put("sEcho", sEcho);
            jsonResponse.put("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
            jsonResponse.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Map rs = (Map) itr.next();
                FleetEquipment eqpmt = new FleetEquipment();
                eqpmt.setVinNumber((String) rs.get("VIN_ID"));
                eqpmt.setMake((String) rs.get("MAKE"));
                eqpmt.setModel((String) rs.get("MODEL"));
                JSONArray row = new JSONArray();
                row.put(eqpmt.getVinNumber()).put(eqpmt.getMake())
                        .put(eqpmt.getModel());
                data.put(row);

            }

            jsonResponse.put("aaData", data);

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<portlet:defineObjects/>

<portlet:resourceURL var="listURL" id="list" escapeXml="false"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#listTable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "<%=listURL.toString()%>",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true
            });
        });

</script></head>
<body>

<table id="listTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>VIN ID</th>
            <th>MAKE</th>
            <th>MODEL</th>
            <th>MODEL1</th>
            <th>Model2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You sure, there isn't any extra word coming along with your above mentioned JSON? I mean like any errors?

Comment: Yes.. I have verified in the link I have mentioned above.

Comment: I understood that you verified, but did you check it in the firebug, as to whats the final outcome. was that a firebug output of the server? May be you are verifying a correct json, but its not taken from the final output. So have you taken it from the Final Output, like firefug?

Comment: Could you post the code trying to parse the JSON on the serverside, please?

Comment: Yes, that is the response I am getting in the firebug.

Comment: Can you run your table through the DataTables debugger and post the debug code so we can see the exact state of your table please: http://debug.datatables.net . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n VIN ID MAKE MODEL ","
status ":200,"
statusText ":"
OK "},"
fnServerData ":"
function (e, j, l, k) {\n k.jqXHR = i.ajax({
        url: e,
        data: j,
        success: function (e) {
            i(k.oInstance).trigger(\"xhr\", k);l(e);}, dataType: \"json\", cache: !1, type: k.sServerMethod, error: function (e, i) {\"parsererror\" == i && alert(\"DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.\");}});\n}", "aoServerParams": [],
            "sServerMethod": "GET",
            "fnFormatNumber": "function (e) {\n if (1000 > e) {\n return e;\n }\n for (var i = e + \"\", e = i.split(\"\"), j = \"\", i = i.length, l = 0; l < i; l++) {\n 0 === l % 3 &&\n 0 !== l && (j = this.oLanguage.sInfoThousands + j), j = e[i - l - 1] + j;\n }\n return j;\n}",
            "aLengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100],
            "iDraw": 1,
            "bDrawing": true,
            "iDrawError": -1,
            "_iDisplayLength": 10,
            "_iDisplayStart": 0,
            "_iDisplayEnd": 0,
            "_iRecordsTotal": 0,
            "_iRecordsDisplay": 0,
            "bJUI": true,
            "oClasses": {
                "sTable": "dataTable",
                "sPagePrevEnabled": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-left",
                "sPagePrevDisabled": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-state-disabled",
                "sPageNextEnabled": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-right",
                "sPageNextDisabled": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-state-disabled",
                "sPageJUINext": "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                "sPageJUIPrev": "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-w",
                "sPageButton": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default",
                "sPageButtonActive": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled",
                "sPageButtonStaticDisabled": "fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled",
                "sPageFirst": "first ui-corner-tl ui-corner-bl",
                "sPagePrevious": "previous",
                "sPageNext": "next",
                "sPageLast": "last ui-corner-tr ui-corner-br",
                "sStripeOdd": "odd",
                "sStripeEven": "even",
                "sRowEmpty": "dataTables_empty",
                "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper",
                "sFilter": "dataTables_filter",
                "sInfo": "dataTables_info",
                "sPaging": "dataTables_paginate fg-buttonset ui-buttonset fg-buttonset-multi ui-buttonset-multi paging_",
                "sLength": "dataTables_length",
                "sProcessing": "dataTables_processing",
                "sSortAsc": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortDesc": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortable": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortableAsc": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortableDesc": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortableNone": "ui-state-default",
                "sSortColumn": "sorting_",
                "sSortJUIAsc": "css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n",
                "sSortJUIDesc": "css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                "sSortJUI": "css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s",
                "sSortJUIAscAllowed": "css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n",
                "sSortJUIDescAllowed": "css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s",
                "sSortJUIWrapper": "DataTables_sort_wrapper",
                "sSortIcon": "DataTables_sort_icon",
                "sScrollWrapper": "dataTables_scroll",
                "sScrollHead": "dataTables_scrollHead ui-state-default",
                "sScrollHeadInner": "dataTables_scrollHeadInner",
                "sScrollBody": "dataTables_scrollBody",
                "sScrollFoot": "dataTables_scrollFoot ui-state-default",
                "sScrollFootInner": "dataTables_scrollFootInner",
                "sFooterTH": "ui-state-default"
            },
            "bFiltered": true,
            "bSorted": true,
            "bSortCellsTop": false,
            "oInit": {
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/wps/myportal/!ut/p/b1/hc09DoJAEIbhs3CCGX5kl3IRdVGiolFkG7Mho2IQEkAKTy8aGwt0ukmeLy8oSE3PctAeWY4LB1Cl7vKzbvOq1MXrV-6RBz73fVMg9-QUw0j6bCLmiGj2IO3BeCakwyJEPuImhkLumLsNLBT2v30C6psgrlhP7Jlki72Fof0BvxJvgAMnEJayulGfShUbDMUISU1Nda8zgs2pIGqjvGkhznR2oYg6Ktb6THBThRde2UMIw3gC131G1Q!!/",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true
            },
            "aoDestroyCallback": [],
            "fnRecordsTotal": "function () {\n return this.oFeatures.bServerSide ? parseInt(this._iRecordsTotal, 10) : this.aiDisplayMaster.length;\n}",
            "fnRecordsDisplay": "function () {\n return this.oFeatures.bServerSide ? parseInt(this._iRecordsDisplay, 10) : this.aiDisplay.length;\n}",
            "fnDisplayEnd": "function () {\n return this.oFeatures.bServerSide ? !1 === this.oFeatures.bPaginate || - 1 == this._iDisplayLength ? this._iDisplayStart + this.aiDisplay.length : Math.min(this._iDisplayStart + this._iDisplayLength, this._iRecordsDisplay) : this._iDisplayEnd;\n}",
            "sInstance": "fleetList",
            "iTabIndex": 0,
            "fnStateLoad": "function (e) {\n var e = this.oApi._fnReadCookie(e.sCookiePrefix + e.sInstance), j;\n try {\n j = \"function\" === typeof i.parseJSON ? i.parseJSON(e) : eval(\"(\" + e + \")\");\n } catch (l) {\n j = null;\n }\n return j;\n}",
            "fnStateSave": "function (e, i) {\n this.oApi._fnCreateCookie(e.sCookiePrefix + e.sInstance, this.oApi._fnJsonString(i), e.iCookieDuration, e.sCookiePrefix, e.fnCookieCallback);\n}",
            "iInitDisplayStart": -1,
            "nTableReinsertBefore": null
            }],
        "tablesDisplayData": [
            []
        ],
        "tablesDisplayExtra": [
            []
        ]
    }
    };
```

Comment: Hah - it breaks the DataTables debugger! Doh. Anyway - it looks to me that your JSON response include stuff such as "script src=\"C:\\workspaces\\WP1\\SpringPortlet\\WebContent\\jquery.dataTables.js\" which is not valid json. Take a look at the response in Firebug - it has content that is not JSON (there is some JSON, but there is other stuff as well).

Comment: I have removed that script src from the jsp page and besides that JSON response I do have the dataTables function and also the table in the response.

Comment: Have a look at this example to see the response that is expected: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html - the DataTables function and the table in the response is not expected - just data for the table.

Comment: I have added my JSP page in the question above. Any clue or idea on why the response is showing the table and javascript? I am struggling with this since last 8 hours..

Answer (score 2):

[image]**[Not an answer to the question, however a tool input]**

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

This tool really help to understand structure of a foreign JSON object. This may not be an answer to your question, however, this has help me understand and parse it well with python code, well it a JSON validator too.