# DataTables json parsing error

Tags: json, datatables, parsing-error

This is a common question and I have researched all the answers Google can provide so I apologize for asking it again.

Firebug shows the response as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

{ "aaData" : [ [ "A",
        "0.67",
        "0.66",
        "0.66",
        "0.66",
        "0.78",
        "1.52",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "-15.38",
        "1970-01-01"
      ],
      [ "AA",
        "0.11",
        "0.12",
        "0.12",
        "0.14",
        "0.12",
        "-8.33",
        "0.00",
        "-14.29",
        "16.67",
        "2013-04-08"
      ],
      [ "AACC",
        "0.03",
        "0.04",
        "0.04",
        "0.04",
        "0.10",
        "-25.00",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "-60.00",
        "2013-03-04"
      ],
      [ "AAN",
        "0.50",
        "0.50",
        "0.50",
        "0.50",
        "0.49",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "2.04",
        "2013-02-04"
      ],
      [ "AAON",
        "0.23",
        "0.23",
        "0.22",
        "0.22",
        "0.20",
        "0.00",
        "4.55",
        "0.00",
        "10.00",
        "2013-03-11"
      ],
      [ "AAP",
        "0.76",
        "0.76",
        "0.76",
        "0.76",
        "0.76",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "2013-02-07"
      ],
      [ "AAPL",
        "13.42",
        "13.34",
        "13.30",
        "13.34",
        "15.45",
        "0.60",
        "0.30",
        "-0.30",
        "-13.66",
        "2013-01-    23"
      ]
    ],
  "iTotalDisplayRecords" : "7",
  "iTotalRecords" : "7",
  "sEcho" : 1
}
```

jsonlint.com says the the json is valid, but why has apache put the Doctype in front of the response? Is this causing the error?

Firebug also reports the headers as :

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  798
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Wed, 23 Jan 2013 09:18:35 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1
```

I am using the server_processing.php script from DataTables with

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $output;
```

The relevant part of my php is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dynamic">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Current Estimate</th>
            <th>7 days ago</th>
            <th>30 days ago</th>
            <th>60 days ago</th>
            <th>90 days ago</th>
            <th>% Change Current</th>
            <th>% Change 7</th>
            <th>% Change 30</th>
            <th>% Change 60</th>
            <th>Next Earnings Date</th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Current Estimate</th>
            <th>7 days ago</th>
            <th>30 days ago</th>
            <th>60 days ago</th>
            <th>90 days ago</th>
            <th>% Change Current</th>
            <th>% Change 7</th>
            <th>% Change 30</th>
            <th>% Change 60</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
   </table>
```

I've lost many hours trying to solve this so am very grateful for any help.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that:
DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.
Also, if I save json output as text file it works perfectly.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8330746/617373  and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494155/json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed

Comment: Already looked at both those. Backslashes do not solve the problem and why should they be needed anyway as the response is valid json? When read from a text file, there is no doctype header and json is accepted. Output from he server includes the doctype (see above). I believe I need to suppress the doctype either in PHP or Apache2 but have not found a method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I had a prepend function that was adding the doctype. Once removed, everything was fine. I found it by moving my code to another development site without the prepend and it worked.